# Laravel условие в маршрутах (Routes)

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть маршруты (пример):

```
Route::get('/test', 'TestController@index');
Route::post('/test', 'TestController@post');
                  .......
Route::get('/testn', 'TestController@indexn');
Route::post('/testn', 'TestController@postn');
```

Требуется добавить к этим маршрутам определённых посредников (middleware) если пользователь аунтифицирован (а если нет, то как есть).

Понимаю что это легко организовать через сами контроллеры, но если маршрутов очень много (и требуется добавить одинаковых посредников), то я считаю что это не практично писать условия с посредниками в контроллерах.

Как сейчас работает:

```
if (auth()->check()){
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['verified', 'ip']], function() {
        Route::get('/test', 'TestController@index');
        Route::post('/test', 'TestController@post');
                  .......
        Route::get('/testn', 'TestController@indexn');
        Route::post('/testn', 'TestController@postn');
    });
} else {
    Route::get('/test', 'TestController@index');
    Route::post('/test', 'TestController@post');
                  .......
    Route::get('/testn', 'TestController@indexn');
    Route::post('/testn', 'TestController@postn');
}
```

Задача отсеять мультиаккаунтсво. Если пользователь не авторизован, сёрфи спокойно (половина материала скрыта пока не авторизуешься), но если авторизован с ip с которого заходил кто-то ещё или проделывал определённые действия, показываю страничку с баном и тд

Требуется ваша помощь, знатоки!

Comment: Может лучше использовать один middleware, а внутри него уже выполнять код в зависимости от условия?

Comment: Я ведь правильно понимаю, что в твоем коде, в зависимости от значения `auth()->check()` будут меняться методы и контроллеры обработки?

Comment: Нет, меняться будут только посредники

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Открываем документацию](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-groups) и читаем

```
Route::middleware(['first', 'second'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        // Uses first & second Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses first & second Middleware
    });
});
```

Вы можете делать вложенные одна в другую группы. Но я считаю, что у вас неправильная логика приложения, которая сама по себе допускает дублирование кода. Так или иначе, а проверок вам не избежать. Ну или вот так

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'ip', 'verified'])->group(function () {...
```

Или объединить всё в одним посредник.
Но опять вообще не ясно, зачем одни и те же роуты проверять.

Comment: Вопрос будьте добры прочтите ещё раз, мне нужно не просто их сгруппировать, а добавить нужный посредник в зависимости от условия, жаль что есть те люди, которые не разобравшись сразу минусуют...

Comment: Ну у вас тогда странная логика приложения. И насколько я знаю ничего готового нет.

Comment: Я по этому и задал вопрос, так как с документацией знаком

Comment: Что вам мешает добавить проверку условия в посреднике? Опять же, в Laravel есть несколько путей для проверки пользователя (Auth::check(), Route::middleware([‘auth’])), так что ответ, данный вам @n.osennij, в точку.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov эммм... А почему нельзя просто проверять при регистрации то, что вы хотите сделать. Или при авторизации непосредственно? И опять же, какой такой контент вы хотите скрыть? Толку от всего этого, если человек просто может не логиниться и серфить. К тому же как насчёт семей или общественных компьютеров. Ip там ведь один. Можете ещё раз подробно описать свою задумку?

Comment: @n.osennij, всё изложено в шапке

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, Route::middleware([‘auth’]) проводит валидацию на авторизацию, т.е если ты не авторизован, то не сможешь пройти по данному маршруту! Это не подходит

Comment: Я всё равно не понимаю. Вот есть главная страница, например. Её может просматривать и авторизованный пользователь и не авторизованный пользователь. Т.е. любой посетитель. А вы хотите, чтобы главную страницу мог просматривать только тот авторизованный пользователь, чей ip не засветился где-то ещё. Что за бред? Смысл? Человек выйдет из аккаунта и будет смотреть себе эту вашу страницу. Что вы городите?

Comment: Прежде чем обуславливать чужую логику бредом, прочтите ещё раз ВСЮ шапку, а не только заголовок

Answer (score 0):

Здраствуйте.

Как быть если нужен доступ через singed url или через auth?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/833183)